# How can I program a group of conditional emails that are sent in order and one by one?

Tags: forms, email, triggers

How can I program a group of conditional emails that are to supposed to be sent one by one, depending on the field of the form the user has selected and also by the order that the users fill it out?

Each user is supposed to get only one email, and the email should arrive in their inbox, and it's also is supposed to be displayed on their screen.

Form example:

> Name
>
> Email
>
> Option a, Option b, Option c
>
> Submit

I want to be able to send out 4 emails (or more) for Option a, 4 emails for Option b, 4 emails for Option c.

Example:

> Option a - Email 1
>
> Option a - Email 2
>
> Option a - Email 3
>
> Option a -Email 4

Let's say:

User 1 fills out the form and selects Option a, he is supposed to get only Option a - Email 1.

User 2 fills out the form and selects Option b, he is supposed to get only Option b - Email 1.

User 3 fills out the form and selects Option a, he is supposed to get only Option a - Email 2.

And so on...

What would be the easiest way to program this form and make a backend so the admin can just edit the emails and options?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post what you have tried so far and where is the exact problem and we will help you out.

Comment: @MehdiBounya please check what I've got in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: No... post your code in the question by editing it and delete this answer.